# can't move to a file below the home directory from the terminal in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I can't move to a file below the home directory from the terminal in Jupyter lab. Specifically, the cd and ls commands do not work for the directories below the home directory. But, ls ../  and cd ../ are OK, and the pwd command works. The jupyter notebook itself works normally, but why?
version
- macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
- Python 3.7.6
- jupyter lab --version 2.1.0

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the terminal is running with a user that is not allowed to do that.
You can see the user with `whoami`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried typing `whoami` in terminal in Jupyter lab, but the user is myself. There doesn't seem to be a problem.